# Getting "No key available with this passphrase." when trying to add a new LVM encryption password

Tags: password, encryption, lvm, ecryptfs

I am getting "No key available with this passphrase" when I try to reset the password for the LVM encryption on my Ubuntu box.

I have tried the following commands:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda5
sudo cryptsetup -y luksAddKey /dev/sda5
sudo cryptsetup -c sha512 -y luksAddKey /dev/sda5
```

I looked in `/proc/crypto` and verified that the sha512 encryption is available. So that one should have worked.

I am not sure why it doesn't work. But I am just trying to set the password to "password" before I leave. This is my last day at this job and I don't want to leave any personal passwords around.

Comment: sha512 is a hash, try with something like `sudo cryptsetup -c aes -y luksAddKey /dev/sda5 --key-slot 1`